# Access nested html elements and set their css

Tags: html, css

The content of an html file is given below and i want to be able to access each of the divs with the id="z" and set them to a different background color using a loop in a js file.

```
<div id="x">
  <div class="y">
       <div id="z">
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="y">
       <div id="z">
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="y">
       <div id="z">
       </div>
  </div>
     .
     .
 </div>
```

The loop

```
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) { 
      $( " ? ? ? " ).css( "background", color[i] );      
}
```

Comment: All you need to do is `$("#z").css( "background", color[i] );`

Comment: Doing this sets the background of only the first div with id z as color[i]

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id. Ids **must** be unique. Use a class instead and do `$('.z').each( function( i ) { $( this ).css( "background", color[i] ); } );`

Comment: Could you provide your whole code, with all variables?

Comment: why not use only just CSS for this? why JS?

Comment: Am using  the JS file since i need to generate random colors for each div with id z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unique ids. In your case instead of ids use classes:

```
<div id="x">
   <div class="y">
           <div class="z">
           </div>
   </div>
   <div class="y">
           <div class="z">
           </div>
   </div>
   <div class="y">
           <div class="z">
           </div>
   </div>
         .
         . 
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$(".z").each(function(i) {
    $(this).css("background", color[i]);
}
```